# Call macro AfterRefresh issue

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I'd like a vbOK message box to appear after my queries have refresh.

I've gone through some of the answers on here already and tried to piece it together but I'm not been able to work out what I am doing wrong.

This is in ThisWorkbook:

```
Dim qtevent As qtclass
-------------------------------------------------

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Set qtevent = New qtclass
Set qtevent.HookedTable = 
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TagData").ListObjects("barTagData").QueryTable

End Sub
-------------------------------------------------

Sub refreshData()

Refresh_Note.Show vbModeless

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

With ThisWorkbook
.Connections("Query - PSTab").OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = True
.Connections("Query - PETab").OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = True
.Connections("Query - barTagData").OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = True

.Connections("Query - PSTab").Refresh
.Connections("Query - PETab").Refresh
.Connections("Query - barTagData").Refresh

End With

DoEvents

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
-------------------------------------------------
```

This is the qtclass module:

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents qt As QueryTable
-------------------------------------------------

Public Property Set HookedTable(q As Excel.QueryTable)
Set qt = q
End Property
-------------------------------------------------

Private Sub qt_AfterRefresh(ByVal Success As Boolean)

MsgBox "qt_AfterRefresh called successfully."
If Success = True Then
Call hideForm
MsgBox "If called Successfully"
End Sub
-------------------------------------------------

Sub hideForm()

Refresh_Note.Hide

End Sub
-------------------------------------------------
```

Any help is appriciated! :) Thanks.

I'm trying call the hideForm sub after the queries have refreshed which will also produce another msg box, stating "Queries Refreshed". This part is already taken care off, but the sub isn't being called AfterRefresh.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one way to do it. For all of your Queries, `Query - PSTab`, `Query - PETab`, `Query - barTagData`, you need to uncheck the "Enable Background refresh" option in the query properties window.

After doing this, the `DoEvents` function should wait until it refreshes the queries. So you can add a `MsgBox` function after the `DoEvents`

[image: Disable Query refresh]